# Would the Valley have made Jerec more powerful than Palpatine or Abeloth?

Tags: star-wars, video-games

In *Star Wars: Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II*, Jerec tries to access the power of the Valley of the Jedi.

If he had succeed, would he have truly become more powerful than Palpatine or even Abeloth?

Comment: I do not think that Palpatine was all that powerful in the force.  He was clearly very manipulative and intelligent.  But in terms of raw force power he never really demonstrated anything that would indicate a level of inherent power beyond the average Sith.  Certianly not to a level comparable to Abeloth

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, we must know what power Jerec was searching in the valley. It's been about 15 years since I played this game, so I will rely on [starwars.wikia article on Jerec, Apotheosis section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jerec#Apotheosis) for this.

> Using the Force, he opened the dome and leaped inside to the absolute heart of the Valley's power. There, he engaged in meditation, hovering cross-legged among the captive spirits of the Jedi and Sith of ages past as he bent them to his will and leeched their strength. Reveling in the Force energies of the Valley, **he reached a state of near-apotheosis in which he gained total omniscience.** At long last, total knowledge—something which he had coveted for countless years—was completely, fully in his grasp, and untold power came with it.

I don't remember the details, but he somehow accessed the power of the Valley. Omniscience is a great power, but it could not saved him from Katarn.

Would he have he become more powerful than Palpatine or Abeloth? It's hard to tell, as not much is know about the power the valley grants. We can't put them in a cage and watch to see who is victorious. It's pure speculation, but my feeling is he would have held his own against Palpatine, but he would not have stood a chance against Abeloth.

Would he have become more powerful than you can possibly imagine? Probably, from a certain point of view, but I have a bad feeling about this...

Comment: I agree. Great answer, yet I don't think he tapped all of the Valleys power before he was killed.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if jerec was able to reach a state of near apotheosis he might be able to create new species or a parallel universe or realm of his own. He might even be able to travel back in time and of course forsee the future. it is possible that he might even be able to make all life forms his subordinates to do his bidding, he might even have been able to resurrect legendary sith.  we can speculate that if he reached a near perfect state that he could be hypothetically equal or greater to palpatine with the knowledge this holy site had to offer.  And this isn't taking into consideration that he was a tenured professor of archaeology or something like that, and he spoke multiple languages. In my opinion he was already a threat to both the sith and jedi back in the days of the republic he was already a knight back then.But what I have a problem with is that when he was absorbing the force at the force well: how he was not able to see or forsee his demise at the hands of  a farmer
boy who was really unrefined . this shows an inconsistancy it shows that even at a near perfect state he could not defeat a farmer from sulon.

Answer (score 0):

Wookieepedia forgets to mention that Jerec accessed half the Jedi Valley's power, and he took almost all power. But I guess we can say he's almost equal with DE Sidious at the current. Had Kyle not stripped his powers, he would have become the most powerful Force entity from the Star Wars Universe,and he'd have surpassed even the Ones and could kill them with a mere thought.

This is an opponent that even Nihilus in a straight combat would fear and not dare to challenge (he would flee away of a god-like entity)

And I use Nihilus as a reference,because we know his drain is unblockable and the greatest one ever, similar to Galactus that consumes planets in minutes and creatures, in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It says in game that with the power he would be able to destroy planets with a whisper, so yes he would have become more powerful than any other force user at the time (probably ever)

Comment: It would be a great thing if you could add _when_ it's said in the game, or even include a clip/screenshot of it!